# Is it possible to make input as password in Acumatica

Tags: erp, acumatica

In configuration screen I need to have storage of passwords. Also I want to make it invisible for others ( displayed as stars ). How should I mark DAC class text field and/or modify PXTextEdit control in order to get this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found answer on my question:

```
    <px:PXTextEdit ID="edPassword" runat="server" DataField="Password" TextMode="Password" />
```

I want to extend my answer with another part. For now it's also possible to add attribute PXRSACryptString. For example like this:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Password")]
[PXRSACryptString(512, IsUnicode = true)]
public virtual string SPassword { get; set; }
```